# Trivial representation from the row-shape Young diagram

Tags: representation-theory

For the Young diagram $\lambda$ which is the row with, say $d$ squares, i.e. $\lambda = (d)$, the corresponding Young symmetrizer is

$c_\lambda = \sum\limits_{g\in\mathfrak S_d}g$

such that the image of $c_\lambda$ is the vector space $\text{Sym}^dV$ for chosen vector space $V$. Then, unless $\dim V=1$ this image apparently has dimension larger than 1, and hence cannot be irreducible trivial representation of $\mathfrak S_d$ (which is 1-dimensional).

Since we know that $\lambda$ should define trivial representation, my argument is wrong at some point. Please help to understand where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to refresh my memory about Young symmetrizers, I read through the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_symmetrizer


There, it says that the irreducible representation corresponding to the Young symmetrizer $c_\lambda$ ist the $\mathbb C S_n$-left ideal $\mathbb C S_n c_\lambda$ in the group algebra $\mathbb C S_n$. For $\lambda = (n)$ we have $c_{(n)} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sigma$. So, $\mathbb C S_n c_{(n)} = \mathbb C c_{(n)}$ really is the one-dimensional trivial representation of $S_n$.


If $S_n$ acts on the n-fold tensor product of an arbitrary vector space by permuting factors, then the image of $c_{(n)}$ is not necessarily one-dimensional, as you noted.